# shared_ptr deleter issue

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, shared-ptr

I am trying to attach deleter function in `shared_ptr` as we want to pool my memory but getting an strange error. Please help me to resolve this error:

```
template<std::size_t size> class Allocator{
public:
    template<typename T> void Release(T *ptr)
    {

    }
    template<typename T> void GetMemory(std::shared_ptr<T> &item)
    {
        T *ptr = new T();
        //my pain point is
        item =  std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr, 
        std::bind(&Allocator<size>::Release, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
};
```

The error is:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'void GetMemory(std::share_ptr<T> &item)  unsigned int size = 10u]':
prog.cpp:316:15:   required from here
prog.cpp:226:19: error: no matching function for call to 'bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, Pool<10u>*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&)'
          std::bind(&Pool<test>::Release, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Comment: What's the definition of `Pool::Release`? Sounds as if it has multiple overloads. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, might copy issue:
std::bind(&Allocator<size>::Release, this, std::placeholders::_1));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<std::size_t size> class Allocator{
public:
    template<typename T> void Release(T *ptr)
    {

    }
    template<typename T> void GetMemory(std::share_ptr<T> &item)
    {
        T *ptr = new T();
        //my pain point is
        item =  std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr, 
        std::bind(&Allocator<size>::Release, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
};
```

You can use a lambda instead:

```
item =  std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr, [&](auto x) { this->Release(x); });
```

But if you must use `std::bind`, you have to do this:

```
item =  std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr, 
    std::bind(&Allocator<size>::template Release<T>, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I will explore it later. Or give me some pointer. Let me check run time effect :)